# I have to restart nfs service every time after I boot Ubuntu Server 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, nfs4

After a reboot of my Ubuntu server, the nfs shares and not accessible.  I have to do `sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart` and then clients can mount the nfs shares just fine.  The service is started at boot, and I've tried adding this line to `rc.local` but I still have to actually log in and run the command manually before clients can connect.  I only have to do this once after the server boots up, and then it works fine from then on.

Any idea why it is requiring this manual restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It is apparently a problem with name resolution.  I was using dns names in my export definitions.  When I changed the dns names to ip addresses, then it works find after a restart.  I would rather use the names, but I guess I'll live with using ip addresses for now since I don't expect them to change any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the start up script.

Comment: The environment or $PATH might be different when the script is run during startup vs. when you run it by hand causing different results.

Comment: The startup script is the one provided by the Ubuntu apt repo, just fyi.  @Chris - the perms are the same as all other start scripts: 755 owned by root.root.

Comment: @mtinberg - that would make sense.  Any idea what part of the environment could be affecting it?

Comment: I would expect that the script does work or it would be broken for everybody so it must be something different about your local setup.